# Null Pointer Exception at Array Class

Tags: java, exception, object, printing, null

Every time when I make a class and other class that will be an array where i will store the first class objects and i call a method ,i receive a nullPointerEception..

ex:

```
public class person {

    private String name,int age;
    public Class()//constructor

    public void print() {

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(name);

        //.........others methods
    }
}

public class personList {

    person[] pl = new person[10];
    int i=0;

    public void add(person p) {

        pl[i]=p;
        i++
    }

    public void print() {

        for(int j=0;j<pl.length;j++)
        {
            pl[j].print();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is here: `pl[j].print();`

The object `p[j]` isn't null ,because I initiate in Main `file(p=new person("Maxim",17),pl.add(p)).`

Even if I intializate from Main like this `p[0]=.....,p[1]=...` I receive the same error.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting so many downvotes. This is the same type of question that many new Java programmers have.

Comment: @mttdbrd it's maybe the lack of effort that went into the question.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to tell that to the OP than just hit downvote?

Comment: @Thomas, I guess it could be that. But this is a helping website. Downvotes don't help. Reformatting, asking questions, giving answers: that helps new users.

Comment: @mttdbrd that's true, at least one should explain downvotes if it hasn't been stated already. That said I also can only guess the reason behind those downvotes.

Comment: @OP this should help you with future questions, since the more effort you put into the question the more it will motivate people to try and help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

`person[] pl = new person[10];` will create an array of *length* 10 with all elements being null.

Thus, if you don't initialize all 10 elements your `print()` method will eventually throw a NullPointerException.

You seem to only call `add(p)` once, i.e. you only intialize element at index 0 to a non-null value and thus when `j` reaches value/index 1, `person[j]` *will* be null.

To fix this you should change your loop to `for(int j=0;j<i;j++)`, assuming that `print()` is a method of class `personList` (your posts formatting makes it hard to determine).

A few side notes:

- Please check the Java coding conventions and stick to them, since that will make it easier for others to read your code (and it will probably even help you). At least stick to the convention on class names which should be camel case and start with an upper case letter, e.g. `PersonList` not `personList`.
- Instead of using an array and a counter, e.g. `Person[]` and `i`, it would be better to use a list or some other collection, e.g. `List<Person>`. That way the loop could become `for( Person p : pl) { p.print() }` and you'd also not be restricted to 10 elements.

Comment: How can I create array with unknown numer of elements ?In C++ is with dynamic allocation.In java?

Comment: @user3401592 in Java you'd use a collection, e.g. a `List` with one implementation being `ArrayList`, if you don't know the number of elements when creating the collection. If you do, you can just pass that number to the array constructor, e.g. `int numElements = 3; int[] a = new int[numElements];`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
person[] pl = new person[10];
```

You need to initialize each Person object in the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pl.length; i++)
{
    pl[i] = new Person();

}
```

Your constructor for Person is also wrong. It should be

```
public Person(){...}
```

not

```
public Class(){...}
```